# Autocomplete json_encode return by column

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm using the autocomplete UI for my search box. Below is my php code:

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $value = $_GET['term'] . '%';
        $return_arr = array();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobname LIKE ? or formtype LIKE ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $value, $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($entryid, $jobnumber, $jobname, $formtype, $date);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] = $jobname;
            $return_arr[] = $formtype;
        }

        echo json_encode($return_arr);

    }
?>
```

Everything works perfectly fine. But I kind of want for the while statement to return all `$jobname` values first before the `$formtype` values. In short, I want the values to be returned by column and not by row. I'm not sure how it is possible because I tried putting them inside do while and foreach statements but both didn't work for me.

Also for some reason, when I create another echo statement, the:

```
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . But I kind of want for the while statement to return all $jobname values first before the $formtype values.

Build two arrays and then merge them:

```
$ar1 = [];
$ar2 = [];
while($stmt->fetch()) {

$arr1[] =  $jobname;
$arr2[] =  $formtype;

  }
$return_arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

> Also for some reason, when I create another echo statement, the:
>   echo json_encode($return_arr);
>   stops working.

Because autocomplete expects json object and you want to try give him json object and something else

Comment: I tried creating two arrays before but it didn't come to me that merging is an option. Thanks a lot. This is just what I needed.